# BASH: How to determine file name format is as follows -> "AA [0-9][0-9][0-9].pdf"

Tags: bash

I'm trying to determine if a file has the format "AA [0-9][0-9][0-9].

This is what I have

```
for file in *.pdf; do
   if [ ${file}=="AA"[[:space:]][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]; then
      #perform action
   fi
```

Yet I am getting the error "AA: unary operator expected"

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Pattern matching must be done with the `bash` conditional expression, not the `[` command.

```
for file in *.pdf; do
    if [[ $file = AA\ [0-9][0-9][0-9].pdf ]]; then
        ...
    fi
done
```

Comment: Hm this is returning nothing for me where I have "AA 123.pdf" and AA 246.pdf" in the current directory

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the full pattern. Pattern-matching is also all-or-nothing; you can't just match a prefix by itself. Appending `*` is sufficient to create a pattern that matches a prefix, but I've modified the answer to match exactly PDF files.

Answer (score 2):

Your original statement will never match, because it doesn't end in .pdf, but I assume you mean "AA [0-9][0-9][0-9].pdf"

```
for file in *.pdf ; do
   if expr "$file" : 'AA [0-9][0-9][0-9].pdf' >/dev/null; then
      #perform action
   fi
done
```

Comment: This is correct, except you don't need the `^` anchor.  The regexp in `string : regexp` is always implicitly anchored at the beginning.  Also, you probably should use single quotes around the regexp, to prevent expansion by the shell before matching.

Comment: `expr` is good to know for portability, but it isn't necessary in `bash`.